# How to authenticate user on index page in Yii

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I am developing a web using Yii.

When I create a module using gii code generator, it will automatically add authentication to admin page of that particular model and controller.

But I want to add user authentication on index page itself. So, when a user opens website it should ask for login.

I have **index.php** inside the "view\site\" directory and **login.php** is also in the same directory.

I have **sitecontroller.php** in "\controller" directory (as usually)

It's my first project in Yii framework. Someone suggest me how to apply user authentication, when website opens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the following at the top of the SiteController's index() action:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->getId()===null)
            $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
```

It will check if the user is logged. If that's not the case, the page will redirect to login.

In order to avoid any action being accessed by not logged users, you need to modify the accessRules() functions of your controllers:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array(),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array(),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow',
                            'actions'=>array(), 
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',
                            'actions'=>array(), 
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

In each controller, we have that function, and within it we have that four arrays. Each array declares an access rule. In the 'actions' parameter we specify which actions will be affected that access rule, and in 'users' we specify which users will be allow to access the actions. '*' means all users, authenticated or unauthenticated. '@' means only authenticated users, 'admin' means of course only admin members.

If any 'actions' parameters has no actual actions assigned, then just delete than line:

```
        array('allow',
                   'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
```

Comment: It worked fine, but only for index() action. One can user direct url (if know) to view other pages, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've done it finally.

Here is the code, I've added to the **sitecontroller.php**

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl',
    );
}

public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform only 'login' action
            'actions'=>array('login'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' AND 'delete' AND 'index' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete','index'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

So, it's working now.

thanks to all for your valuable replies

Answer (score 1):

This is same as above but as a component so that it needs to be done only once and all controllers needing security can extend this component.

Add a new component in the components directory (`SecurityController.php`):

```php
<?php

class SecurityController extends CController {

   public $breadcrumbs=array();

   public function filters()
   {
      return array(
         'accessControl',
      );
   }

   public function accessRules()
   {
      return array(
         array('allow',
               //'actions'=>array('admin','delete','index'),
               'users'=>array('admin', '@'),
         ),
         array('deny',  // deny all users
               'users'=>array('*'),
         ),
      );
   }
}
```

Now ensure all your controllers that need authentication inherits from `SecurityController`:

```php
<?php

class JSController extends SecurityController {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it for Forcing Login for All Pages in Yii:

http://www.larryullman.com/2010/07/20/forcing-login-for-all-pages-in-yii/

And for forceful login in the index page you can customize

```
public function handleBeginRequest($event)
{
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest && !in_array($_GET['r'],array('site/login'))) {
        Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this posts

[Special Topic - Authentication and Authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth)

[Yii Wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/?tag=authentication)

Check sample Blog App for post controller

Comment: Just define an access control filter for your index.php http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter like on the admin pages.

Comment: I've made according changes and now it gives error for redirect loop :/

Comment: @Rajat the solution given by **alfredo** is working quite fine, according to my need. But then I came up with another issue, that is: **someone can access other pages of website by using direct url,** (if they know) So I'm resolving that issue so no one can access from direct url too..

Comment: If you haven't still solved the problem..add it as a new question..:)

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the SecurityController component suggestion :

> class SecurityController extends CController

Maybe because of a newer version:  I had to extend SecurityController from Controller to make it work. But then it works as a charm